# Chocolate and oil how to store this

Tags: baking

When mixing 16 ounces of chocolate and 4 ounces of oil together and melting it how long will it last ? How should I store it ? Can it cause botulism ?

Comment: Not writing an answer as I can only address one question. I would generally not worry about it causing botulism. As a guideline, I worry about botulism when I plan to store something in an air-tight container for a long period of time, especially at room temperature. Or, if there is garlic or beet or some sort of root product (something in direct contact soil) without having been cooked, in an environment that can't really get air (e.g., and especially, flavored oils with raw garlic).

Comment: Please address these two questions: What kind of chocolate (cacao%) are you using? What kind of oil?  The answers may help with the facilitation of answering your question appropriately as well as more precisely.